# PostgreSQL Upsert For Almost Similar Values

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-update, postgresql-9.5, upsert

I am trying to keep count the hits of similar values (val1,val2) within a specified threshold (± some value).
For exact matches I would use UPSERT, but I can't figure out how to make it work with similar matches.

Given a table `valuetable`

| id | val1 | val2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 2.2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1.7 | 2.2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1.0 | 2.2 | 1 |

and we were to do

```
INSERT INTO valuetable 
VALUES(DEFAULT, 1.2, 2.1, 1) 
ON CONFLICT (val1 ± 0.1,val2 ± 0.1)
DO 
  UPDATE SET count = count + 1
```

We will get the below table where the `count` for `id=1` is incremented because `val1` and `val2` of `id=1` is within the 0.1 range specified.

| id | val1 | val2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 2.2 | `3` |
| 2 | 1.7 | 2.2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1.0 | 2.2 | 1 |

---

If that is possible, there is yet another issue.
If we were to do the query below, both `id=1` and `id=3` meet the criteria.

```
INSERT INTO valuetable 
VALUES(DEFAULT, 1.0, 2.1, 1) 
ON CONFLICT (val1 ± 0.1,val2 ± 0.1)
DO 
  UPDATE SET count = count + 1
```

How do we update the one with highest (or lowest)  `count`(e.g. `id=1` get updated because it has highest `count` of 2 in all matching rows)?

| id | val1 | val2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 2.2 | `3` |
| 2 | 1.7 | 2.2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1.0 | 2.2 | 1 |

**Or** to update the one with smallest (or biggest) net difference (e.g `id=3` get updated because it has a net difference of 0.1 instead of `id=1` 0.2) ?

| id | val1 | val2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 2.2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1.7 | 2.2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1.0 | 2.2 | `2` |

*Note*: There was the thought of normalizing the values, e.g `0.1, 0.2, ...` so exact match would be possible,
but it would be best without resorting to that as `0.1, 0.2, ...` with a threshold of `0.5` would still have the same issue, and `0.5, 1.0, ...` would lose too much context.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do this with explicit logic, not an `upsert`.  I might suggest a two step process:

```
with v as (
      select t.*
      from (values (1.2, 2.1)) v(val1, val2)
     ),
     i as (
      insert into valuetable (val1, val2, count)
          select val1, val2, 0
          from v
          where not exists (select 1
                            from valuetable vt
                            where abs(vt.val1 - v.val1) < 0.1 and
                                  abs(vt.val2 - v.val2) < 0.1
                           )
          returning *
     )
update valuetable vt
    set count = count + 1
    from v
    where abs(vt.val1 - v.val1) < 0.1 and
          abs(vt.val2 - v.val2) < 0.1;
```

This inserts values with a count of "1" and then increments the value for the matching rows.  This is not the most efficient method, but it is simple enough to explain.

An alternative is to normalize the data so the values are in increments of 0.2 along each dimension -- and create a unique dimension for that.  Then you can use an upsert:

```
create unique index unq_t_val1_val2
    on (floor(val1 * 5), floor(val2 * 5));
```

Then you can use `upsert` as in your question.  However, do not create a unique index on `(val1, val2)` separately, because the two will be in coflict.

Comment: Thanks, the decision was to settle on a comfortable increments, however coincidental it was.